# Width in CSS not working correctly

Tags: html, css, forms

So I'm having a really weird issue with my submit button. I'm using `width:100%` on the submit button, and it is in a "wrap" So, basically it should be the full width, but ultimately I can't seem to get it to work. Here's a screen shot of what I'm talking about

[image]

As you can see the input fields are all working correctly with the `width:100%`, but the submit isn't working. Here's the code to the corresponding issue.

The HTML part.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>   
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div>   
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>
```

And the CSS to it.

```css
input[type=submit] {
    font-family: "Avenir", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    height: 52px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #27A6D1;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 52px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
.wrap {
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 52px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Avenir", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 14px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

I can get it to work with something like `width: 109%`, but I would prefer using `100`, and a reason or explanation why this isn't working, Any ideas guys?

Also, [find a fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/qehijana/1/edit).

Comment: please post complete relevant CSS (for input boxes too)

Comment: Are you sure it's the `button`? Maybe the `button` is right and the `inputs` are wrong (i.e. the `inputs` having padding which is actually overflowing the `width: 320px`. **EDIT:** I'd say after you posted your full CSS, that the `inputs` are wrong. The `14px` padding is probably causing the `inputs` to extend beyond the container boundaries...

Comment: As requested. Done. @Ejay

Comment: Here's a fiddle disproving that. http://jsbin.com/qehijana/1/edit @j08691 Could my `body` make that much of a difference?

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/8YahC/  Which browser are you using?

Comment: Is it not because of the padding in the wrap? Is it the same in all browsers, I.E for example

Comment: I just added a fiddle. I'm pretty sure its the button. @War10ck

Comment: input have different paddings :)

Comment: Got rid of the padding. Still the same issue. @GrahamWarrender

Comment: Your padding is actually pushing the first few inputs outside of the container element. Box-sizing:border-box will fix this.

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: It's the input. You can tell when you add a border to the wrap: http://jsbin.com/qehijana/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick fix would be using `box-sizing: border-box` on all input elements in the form, and then declare a uniform width: this will ensure that the width is computed as the final border-box width (inclusive of border widths and paddings).

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can then safely customize the padding for each individual input element (if you desire so), without having to worry how they affect the final width of the element.

Here's a proof-of-concept fiddle constructed based on the markup you have provided ;) http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/kx39z/

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. I'll accept when I can. Also +1 for the fiddle

Comment: @Colourity Thanks :) also added a JSFiddle to demonstrate how `box-sizing: border-box` solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `box-sizing: border-box` to your input class. The right/left padding in your input boxes make them wider than the defined width.

Comment: heh. Just about to post that. :) A fiddle to make @ejay's case. http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/LcbFS/

Comment: Would of marked it as an answer, just that you posted second.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to do that. You can just omit the padding on the wrap and the width on the inputs (they are display: block already). Better to remove some CSS that to add extra for neutralizing the false effects.

Comment: I would take it the other way, i.e., removing a valid style (padding) to avoid its unforeseen effects (increased width) instead of remedying the effects (using box-sizing). Removing padding will remove the white space before and after the text in the text box. _before_ white space can be achieved, I think, by text-indent but what about the right space?

Answer (score 1):

`input { padding: 0 14px; }` makes the input 100% + 28px wide

Answer (score 0):

It is the `padding: 0 14px;` that is breaking the layout (as [JimmyRare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23481958/1064325)).

The accepted solution uses the `box-sizing` property, but some older browsers might not have support to it, and it may cause other side effects.

I'd suggest to do the trick by replacing it with `text-indent: 14px;`.